# Error WHERE SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

```
$query_user = "SELECT camp FROM $username WHERE camp != 'NULL'";
$query_user = mysql_query ($query_user, $conn_host_user) or die (mysql_error());
```

Say:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE camp != 'NULL'' at line 1

I don't understand because work perfectly the code, but say that, why?

Comment: `IS NOT NULL` !=, = etc. doesn't work with NULL.

Comment: `$username` as the table name? Isn't that a typo? Do you have tables for all your users?

Comment: your error says `where camp` and your query sample is `where photo_profile`. Are you sure you're looking at the right query?

Comment: @redreggae: but null is quoted, so it's not an sql null. it's a string that happens to contain `N`, `U`, `L, `L`.

Comment: @ppeterka: $username is the name of the Table.

Comment: @Marc B: I have correct the code, both "camp".

Comment: <> 'NULL' don't work, give the same error.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the following:

```
WHERE camp IS NOT NULL
```

So your query will be:

```
SELECT camp 
FROM $username 
WHERE camp IS NOT NULL
```

Edit, if your table has special characters in it, then you will need to use backticks around the name:

```
SELECT camp 
FROM `$username`
WHERE camp IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE camp IS NOT NULL' at line 1

Comment: @Lory9618 Is `$username` the name of the table?  If so, you might need to enclose it in backticks.

Comment: I tryed to replace $username with the name of the talbe (talbe_1) and work, but I can't work with this; So I tryed `$query_user = "SELECT camp FROM " . $username . " WHERE camp IS NOT NULL";` But don't work again.

Comment: @Lory9618 If you know the table name why are using `$username`?

Comment: $query_user = "SELECT camp FROM '$username' WHERE camp IS NOT NULL"; don't work. Say: Incorrect table name '  '

Comment: because $username change and the name of the table change.

Comment: @Lory9618 Are you defining the `$username` variable somewhere in your code?

Comment: `$username = $_SESSION["username"];` and the echo of this give the name (table_1)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you putting NULL in quotes?

$query_user = "SELECT photo_profile FROM username WHERE photo_profile IS NOT NULL";

$query_user = mysql_query ($query_user, $conn_host_user) or die (mysql_error());

Also assuming the name name was wrong and removing the $ - but this may be right???

Comment: Username is a variable, but don't work with IS NOT NULL; give the same error.

Comment: I'm learning, and I learn from mistakes...so, where is the problem if I have got a DB table for each user? You say that is better have got a DB for each user?

Comment: Ok - so when you have 5 or 6 users - this may be OK. But what if you have 300 or 1000 users. Your Database is going to be huge - and inefficient.
Relational databases are designed so that you dont need to do this. What you would typically do is have a "USER" table, and in that table, all of your users will be in that one table identified by "userID" of some description.